# How to get a more relevant stacktrace (file name and line number) for hhvm fatal error?

Tags: debugging, error-handling, hhvm

I have a legacy hhvm restful api.

I made some changes to its code base and now my local server throws:

```
Syntax only allowed in Hack files (<?hh) or with -v 
Eval.EnableHipHopSyntax=true
```

My current hhvm specific setting inside my php.ini is:

```
; hhvm specific
hhvm.log.level = Warning
hhvm.log.always_log_unhandled_exceptions = true
hhvm.log.runtime_error_reporting_level = 8191
hhvm.mysql.typed_results = false
date.timezone="Europe/Berlin"
hhvm.libxml.ext_entity_whitelist = file,http
```

I checked the log at

```
cat /var/log/hhvm/error.log
```

Yet it is empty.

I do not want to allow hack file syntax but I do want more relevant information on where the error is occurring.

I want to at least know in which file I created the error. Nice to have would be in which line and at which character position within that line occurs. The api is internal, so I do not mind to expose that information for now.

Right now I am going through the git diff, and that is not a very effective way of finding the offending code.

Answer (score 0):

This won't expose the error to the server response but check your sandbox settings.

The error log may be in your hhvm *sandbox*, not inside the main hhvm folder:

```
/var/log/hhvm/sandbox/error.log
```

There you will find the relevant information with the error's context:

```
[Mon May 13 15:40:32 2019] [hphp] [25:7fe693fff700:413:000001] [] \nFatal error: Syntax only allowed in Hack files (<?hh) or with -v Eval.EnableHipHopSyntax=true in /var/www/service/src/Dreamlines/BookingService/Bundle/OperatorBundle/Soap/Call/CallBuilderFactory.php on line 177
```